# Bitwise operation changing order of bits

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, avr, atmega

So my excercise is to change order of bits so:

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

will be

```
3 2 7 6 1 0 5 4
```

I'm struggling with figuring this out. I'm trying to use `rol` method to rotate them so I would get `3 2 1 0 7 6 5 4` which would be at least a little bit closer. But the first bit that goes out of scope isn't carried through the second one is my example that I use is `0000 1111`

code:

```
  ldi  r16,$0F   - 0000 1111
       rol  r16  - 0001 1110
       rol  r16  - 0011 1100
       rol  r16  - 0111 1000
       rol  r16  - 1111 0000
       rol  r16  - 1110 000(0 - should be 1) - C was 0, now 1
       rol  r16  - 1100 0001
```

AVR's `rol` rotates through carry; it's an alias for `adc r16,r16`.  ([Online manual](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-61A4FA30-4426-42D7-B199-0EBF064BF9E1.html), or [PDF](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/AVR-Instruction-Set-Manual-DS40002198A.pdf#page=112))

---

> UPDATE
> I've read in the exercise that we should flip bits 5 4 3 2 and then use shifts and rotate to get that order so here is my code

```
       ldi  r16,$0F
       ldi  r17,$3C
       eor  r16,r17
       lsl  r16
       lsl  r16
```

so r16 is `0000 1111` r17 is `0011 1100` then i use XOR gate to get in r16 `0011 0011` and then i want to shift twice to the left with lsl so i get `0110 0110` but after I do the second shift I get: `0011 0001` instead of `1100 1100` and I'm not really sure why is that happening.

> UPDATE 2 The previous code didn't work because the program didn't know what to do after executing last function so it went back to the beggining giving me bad result the solution is `end:  rjmp  end` which forces program to infinitely jump to this line over and over again

```
       ldi  r16,$0F
       ldi  r17,$3C
       eor  r16,r17
       lsl  r16
       lsl  r16
       end:  rjmp  end
```

Comment: This is not merely changing order of bits ... why doesn't an array work?

Comment: @WhatsUp This is changing order of bits. And array would be an overkill. I believe the OP is intended to solve this with logical operators.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Aha I see, he wants that `bit 7` goes to `bit 5`, etc. is that right?

Comment: @WhatsUp Yes, that's it. However the OP has not specified any architecture for us to answer (assembly looks like AVR).

Comment: Yes it is AVR ATmega 8535 and could you please take a look at the update?

Comment: @MargaretBloom Yes, `r16` sounds like AVR.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something at the end I've added one more lsl and it is working I guess i need somehow to terminate the program after last function? because it goes back to the beggining that is why it screws up

Comment: AVR is not my forte, but I believe you are not approaching the problem the right way. You should have an input register and manipulate that.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter version, making use of the `T` flags can be this:

```
;Input: r16
;Output: r16

ror r16        ;r16 = 0 7 6 5   4 3 2 1
ror r16        ;r16 = 1 0 7 6   5 4 3 2
mov r17, r16   ;r17 = 1 0 7 6   5 4 3 2

ror r16        ;r16 = 2 1 0 7   6 5 4 3
ror r16        ;r16 = 3 2 1 0   7 6 5 4

bst r17, 7     ;T = 1
bld r17, 3     ;r17 = 1 0 7 6   1 4 3 2
bst r17, 6     ;T = 0
bld r17, 2     ;r17 = 1 0 7 6   1 0 3 2

andi r17, $3c  ;r17 = - - 7 6   1 0 - -
andi r16, $c3  ;r16 = 3 2 - -   - - 5 4

or r16, r17    ;r16 = 3 2 7 6   1 0 5 4
```

**Nota Bene**
Your attempts at solving this exercise show that you haven't really understood (low level) programming yet.
I suggest you taking some times to internalize the concepts you are studying.

Comment: +1 for shortest sequence, and for showing the OP how to properly comment code for keeping track of data movement.  And for taking advantage of architecture features that are useful.  It's not an architecture I know at all, so it's neat to see what tricks non-x86 CPUs can do.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, it assumes that the `ror` instruction actually rotates the register into itself, in reality - the `ror` instruction actually rotates bit 0 into the carry bit,  not into bit  7 as your first comment suggest. Simulating this code in atmel studio confirms this answer to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but I would do the following (input and return in `R16`):

```
MOV R17, R16
SWAP R16
ANDI R16, 0b11000011              
                    
LSR R17
ROR R18                                  
LSR R17
ROR R18

ANDI R17, 0b00110000
SWAP R18

OR R16, R17
OR R16, R18
```

Answer (score 1):

We can cheat and look what avr-gcc would generate for

```cpp
uint8_t mix (uint8_t bits)
{
  return __builtin_avr_insert_bits (0x32761054, bits, 0);
}
```

The generated assembly is:

```
mix:
    swap r24
    mov r0,r24
    bst r0,2
    bld r24,4
    bst r0,3
    bld r24,5
    bst r0,4
    bld r24,2
    bst r0,5
    bld r24,3
    ret
```

So the compiler does it in 10 instructions and without the requirement of an upper register. It needs a scratch register R0.  When the input does not overlap the output, then no scratch register is reqired, but it still takes 10 instructions.

For a documentation, see [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Built-in-Functions.html) for `__bultin_avr_insert_bits`.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo assembly (byte stored in `r1`):

```
mov r2, r1
mov r3, r2
mov r4, r3

shr r1, 4
shl r2, 2
shr r3, 2
shl r4, 4

and r1, 0x03
and r2, 0x0C
and r3, 0x30
and r4, 0xC0

xor r4, r3
xor r3, r2
xor r2, r1
```

Comment: Am I wrong thinking that this computes `5 4 7 6 1 0 3 2` and that the xor could be simply an or?

Comment: AVR only has shift-by-1, so keep in mind that `shr r2, 2` is two `lsr` instructions.  But `shr r1, 4` can be `swap r1` (swap nibbles) since you're about to mask away the high half anyway.  (https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

I would do it by brute force:

```
ldi   r16, $0F (or any number, your input)
eor   r18, r18
mov   r17, r16
andi  r17, $C0
lsr   r17
lsr   r17
or    r18, r17
mov   r17, r16
andi  r17, $30
lsr   r17
lsr   r17
lsr   r17
lsr   r17
or    r18, r17
mov   r17, r16
andi  r17, $0C
lsl   r17
lsl   r17
lsl   r17
lsl   r17
or    r18, r17
mov   r17, r16
andi  r17, $03
lsl   r17
lsl   r17
or    r18, r17 (the output is `r18`)
```